# How can I convert my conversion function to a lambda expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a C++ code with basic conversion functions, such as the following:

```
void convert(double *x_out, double *y_out, double *x_in, double *y_in)
{
    *x_out = *x_in;
    *y_out = *y_in;
}
```

I then have another function later in my code which takes a function pointer to a conversion function.

```
void process(void (*converter)(double *x_out, double *y_out, double *x_in, double *y_in), double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    (*converter)(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    // do something
    return something;
}
```

`process` is called elsewhere in the code.

```
void my_func(...args...)
{
    process(&convert, _x1_, _y1_, _x2_, _y2_);
}
```

I want to use a lambda function instead of the function pointer approach.

I can't quite get my head around lambdas.

My best guess so far from reading this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda this http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html and this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd293608.aspx is:

```
void my_func(double _x1_, double _y1_, double _x2_, double _y2_)
{

    [&_x1_, &_x2_, &_y1_, &_y2_] -> void
    {
        double x_in = _x1_;
        double y_in = _y1_;
        double x_out = x_in;
        double y_out = y_in;

        // return
        _x2_ = x_out;
        _y2_ = y_out;    
    }

    process(what goes here?, _x1_, _y1_, _x2_, _y2_);

}
```

I'm fairly sure the declaration of the lambda goes inside the function `my_func` itself, so that it can capture the local arguments/variables.

But I'm not sure how to call it from `process()`?

Edits: To answer the questions below,

There is a function, `process` which acts on pairs of data, x and y, but before process operates on this data, it must be converted using a translation function. The example I have given as a translation is trivially, x->x y->y, but a more interesting one might be x->2x, y->0.5y.

Error Message:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from
‘namespace::classname::my_func(uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t,
uint32_t)::<lambda(int32_t*, const int32_t*, int32_t*, const
int32_t*)>’ to ‘void (namespace::classname::*)(int32_t*, const
int32_t*, int32_t*, const int32_t*) {aka void
(namespace::classname::*)(int*, const int*, int*, const int*)}’
```

Arguments in examples should have been `int32_t` rather than double, but this is clearly not of the upmost importance.

Comment: Can you change `process`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Simply using lambda instead of a function pointer is an XY problem. If you tell us what you really need, we can suggest a proper solution. Right now I can only lecture you on lambdas in general, but this would be reiteration of specification.

Comment: @SergeyA Does my edit help at all?

Answer (score 2):

Non-capturing lambdas can be converted to function pointers seamlessly. And you do not seem to need captures here. Following code would work:

```
void my_func(double _x1_, double _y1_, double _x2_, double _y2_)
{

    auto lam = [](double* x_in, double* y_in, double* x_out, double* y_out)
    {
        *x_out = *x_in;
        *y_out = *y_in;
    };

    process(lam, _x1_, _y1_, _x2_, _y2_);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using auto everywhere?

Comment: `auto*` is redundant.  You can simply use `auto`.

Comment: What is `lam` is it a function name or a variable?

Comment: lambda itself has to be `auto`, lam is a `lambda expression`, convertible to function pointer. It's type is unknown. As for the arguments, I was not sure what are your original args. You can replace it with actual types. As a matter of fact, I will replace it now.

Comment: I get an error message when I try to implement this, please see above edit

Comment: @user3728501, you need to post the full relevant code. And the compiler.

Comment: @SergeyA Unfortunately I can't do that.

Comment: @user3728501 than I can't help you, unfortuante as it is.